# IOS Local Notification at specific time

Tags: ios, background, repeat, uilocalnotification, countdowntimer

Below is what I am trying to achieve.
Show local notification to the user about say sunrise/sunset time.
Say sunrise time is at 05:30AM and sunset time at 06:30PM.
Current time is 07:00PM, when the user enables the notification feature then every one hour show
sunrise notification with info time left for sunrise ( that is x hours and y mins left)
Once the time left for sunrise is less than 60 mins, then change the interval from one hour to say 10 mins. Finally when the time left for sunrise is less than 10 mins, then show notification for every minute. When the time for sunrise is reached repeat the same for sunset. This goes on till the user disable this feature via app settings.

Showing a countdown timer is also fine with in a notification if that doesn't drain the battery.

What I have achieved is fire a local notification at a specific time. Appreciate any guidance. I am new to IOS development.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.title = title
      content.body = body
      content.categoryIdentifier = "sdf"
      
      if let info = userInfo {
        content.userInfo = info
      }
      
      content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
      
      var comp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
      comp.minute = comp.minute! + 2
      
      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: comp, repeats: false)
      
      //let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
      
      let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test", content: content, trigger: trigger)
      
      center.add(request)
```

Comment: You have algorithm written down - what have you tried to achieve it ? Where do you have exact problem ? checking current date ? Checking differences between dates ? Showing notifications ?

You are asking for many different topics - it will be easier to help you out if you narrow down the problem to single topic.

Comment: You will have to schedule multiple notifications for the desired times. Note there is a limit to how many notifications you can schedule and if you reach that limit you will probably need the user to open your app so that you can schedule more.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski "Where do you have exact problem ?"  Exact problem to me is how to start.  Say when the user enable this feature I will set the first time. This notification is shown to user. Then how to set the next notification? Or as suggested by Paulw11 in the other comment, I should set the notifications all in one go and let the system (IOS) do the task, which may work or may not as there are limit on number of notifications. I can manage with algorithm. All I need to know is when one notification is shown then can I set a new notification? or use any service/alarm ??
Thanks